# powershell scheduled task trigger with variable

Tags: windows, powershell-4.0

Need to make a script where the script will read the date from text file, then add the time in the variable.  Use the variable in the script and make a scheduled task at remote computer.

```
$Reboot_Dt = Get-Content "C:\Reboot_Dt.txt"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SRV_Dest -Credential $cred -Scriptblock {
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" -Argument "/k Shutdown /r /t 00'" 'Reboot by script Wrt. Windows Update
    $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At '$Reboot_Dt'
    $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
    Register-ScheduledTask 'WinUpd_Reboot' -Action $taskAction -Trigger $Trigger -Principal $principal
}
```

Error :-

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'At'. Cannot
> convert value "$Reboot_Dt" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String
> was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger], ParameterBindin...mationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-ScheduledTaskTrigger
> + PSComputerName        : xxxxxxxxx
>
> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Trigger'. The argument is null
> or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try
> the command again.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Register-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Register-ScheduledTask
> + PSComputerName        : xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Need to create a scheduled task at remote machine, purpose is to reboot the machine on a specific date (The date needs to be read from a text file). Via Get-content the date will be stored in a variable, which will be added by time.  Afterwards this variable is used by New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $Reboot_Dt